# Does Haskell allow a let expression for multiple pattern matchings?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, pattern-matching, let

Let's say I have a function which does some computation, with several patterns; implemented in the form of pattern matching.

Most of these patterns do (along with other things different from one to another) a treatment on a parameter, for which I use an intermediary variable in a `let` expression. But I find it really redundant to have the same `let` on many patterns, and I wonder if there is a way to define a `let` for several patterns?

Here is an example of my duplicated `let` :

```
data MyType a = Something a | Another Int [a]

myFunc (Something x) = -- return something, this isn't the point here
myFunc (Another 0 xs) =
    let intermediary = some $ treatment xs
    in doSthg intermediary 1 
myFunc (Another 1 (x:xs)) =
    let intermediary = some $ treatment xs
    in doSthg1 intermediary 1 x
myFunc (Another 2 (x:x':xs)) =
    let intermediary = some $ treatment xs
    in doSthg2 intermediary 2 x x'
```

You can see that the parameter `xs` is always present when I use it for `intermediary`, and this could be factorised.
It could easily be achieved by using a helper function but I was wondering if what I am asking is possible without one. Please try to keep it simple for a beginner, and I hope my example is clear enough.

Comment: Nope!  Gotta use a separate function and pass it as a parameter explicitly to factor out repeated code.  As far as Haskell is concerned, the above occurrences of `xs` are completely different variables (because they have different binding sites).

Comment: Thanks! Now I've got another question: did you intend that the third and fourth equations never match? Because `xs` matches any list... Did you reverse the order of equations?

Comment: I wrote this in order to illustrate that `xs` is extracted from pattern matching in several patterns but doesn't always have the same meaning (otherwise pattern matching would have no interest : there would only be one pattern). What's done with it in the example is not important; but in my code `y` is replaced with real values so the later patterns match. But you're right again so I will edit it with a concrete type to make the whole thing more understandable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This *particular* problem can be worked around as follows:

```
myFunc2 (Something x) = returnSomething x
myFunc2 (Another n ys) = 
    let xs = drop n ys
        x = head ys 
        x' = head (tail ys)
        intermediate = some $ treatment xs 
    in case n of
        0 -> doSomething intermediate n
        1 -> doSomething1 intermediate n x
        2 -> doSomething2 intermediate n x x'
```

Thanks to lazy evaluation `x` and `x'` will be only evaluated if their value is needed.

**However** - and this is a big however! - your code will give a runtime error when you try to call `myFunc2 (Another 2 [])` (and if `doSomething2` actually uses `x`!) because to find out what `x` is, we need to evaluate `head ys` - and that'll crash for an empty list. The code you gave as an example also won't work (another runtime error) for `Another 2 []` since there's no matching pattern, but there it's easier to supply a fall-back case.

This might not be a problem if you control the input and always make sure that the list in `Another` is long enough, but it's important to be aware of this issue!

Comment: This is effectively not a problem in my code because `Another` objects can not be built with empty lists. +1, it does the trick very well

Comment: @tehinternetsismadeofcatz: The whole problem has as a strong 'interpreter for a stack language'-feel to it, so if you compile right, you will run right - the type system is just not (but it's close!) strong enough to express what you *know* about the inputs. You could also consider changing your `MyType` to express the things you know about the arguments more clearly, but that's a lot of work...